# Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed with an invalid user

Tags: linux, ssh, chef-infra, ssh-keys, knife

Having an issue when executing '`knife ssh`' command. 
I've configured properly the SSH keys for remote connection so that seems to work fine when trying to connect manually doing: `ssh root@myhost.domain.com` cause it automatically gives me access to `myhost.domain.com` without request for a password.

After that, I tried to run the following knife command to execute a recipe in my remote machine but I'm getting this error:

```
# knife ssh -C 1 "tags:amx_host AND chef_environment:dev" "chef-client -o recipe[amx]" -i root_dev -x root
WARNING: Failed to connect to myhost.domain.com -- Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user root@myhost.domain.com@myhost.domain.com
```

Seems like knife is identifying an invalid user name `root@myhost.domain.com` which should be just `root` instead.

Please, does anyone have any clues on how can I avoid this error or why SSH is taking a wrong user: `root@myhost.domain.com` instead of just `root`?

Answer (score 0):

Typo issue: was taking a non-existing identity key file: root-dev for the remote connection